# Facing the pathauto issue from Drupal 8 to 9 conversion?

Tags: drupal-9

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "path.alias_manager". Did you mean this: "path_alias.manager"? in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 156 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

    Drupal::service('path.alias_manager') (Line: 378)
    custom_hreflang_page_attachments_alter(Array, NULL, NULL) (Line: 539)
    Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter('page_attachments', Array) (Line: 319)
    Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->invokePageAttachmentHooks(Array) (Line: 288)
    Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 132)
    Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
    Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
    call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
    Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 163)
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
    Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
    Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
    Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
    Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Facing this issue. How to solve this? When I click on user page, open the content facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the service name should be "path_alias.manager" rather than "path.alias_manager" (note the switched locations of underscore and period).